# In typescript, what do we call this "pattern matching" like function declaration?

Tags: typescript, destructuring

So I was playing around with typescript at http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/. Discovering that we could actually do the following to take in object's property/array element directly.

Example:

```
function([first: int, second: int]): int{
  return first + second;
}

function([first: any, person: {name: string}]): string{
  return name;
}
```

However, I can't find anywhere online which talks about this "pattern matching"-like feature. (I love pattern matching; and haskell.)

This feature is so powerful. I want to know what they're called in typescript. So that I can have some further reading on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that valid, though? It doesn't work in the Playground: `int` is not a type, and `[first: number, second: number]` doesn't work. The closest thing I know of is `function([first, second]:[number, number]):number`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called *destructuring*; the syntax you're hinting at there is specifically *parameter destructuring*.

It's actually an ES6 feature and you can read about it [under the MDN topic "destructuring assignment"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thank you so much. :) Wow it is in ES6! How little do I know! Well, I'd keep on calling it "pattern matching". haha!

Answer (score 3):

Its destructuring : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/destructuring.html

Please don't call it pattern matching as that is its own thing and has a seperate spec : https://gist.github.com/bterlson/da8f02b95b484cd4f8d9

Comment: You are quite right. This is destructuring, pattern matching would require the ability to match values. (which involves cases). Thanks for your answer. :)